# Property 'pipe' doesn't exist on type 'HttpParams' Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I just started learning Angular.
I found a guide in YouTube but while I was copying the code there was an error.

**My task**

1. I need to get data from *fakestoreapi.com/products* that matches my interface *IProduct*
2. Elements should be 5
3. Should be a 2 second delay

My code:
`

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpParams} from "@angular/common/http";
import {catchError, delay, Observable} from "rxjs";
import {IProduct} from "../models/product";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductsService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

    }

    getAll(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
        return this.http.get<IProduct[]>("https://fakestoreapi.com/products", {
            params: new HttpParams({
                fromObject: {limit: 5}
            }).pipe( //error 
                delay(2000)
            )
        });
    }
}
```

`

I didn't find this method in documentation, but it was in guide!

Screenshot of guide:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2s7I.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pipe` part is positioned at the wrong place.

```
return this.http
           .get<IProduct[]>("https://fakestoreapi.com/products", {
              params: new HttpParams({
                fromObject: {limit: 5}
              })
            })
            .pipe( //error 
                delay(2000)
            );
```

Check the official documentation of [Angular Http Client](https://angular.io/guide/http)